vertex-connectivity and adjacency between large sets?
A graph $G$ is called $t$-joined if for any two disjoint vertex subset $S,T$, each of size at least $t$, there is an edge between them.
Then a $k$-vertex connected graph $G$ is $\frac{n-(k-1)}{2}$-joined, where $n=|V(G)|$: suppose not and there are two disjoint vertex sets $S,T$, each of size at least $\frac{n-(k-1)}{2}$. Then removing at most $k-1$ vertex in $V(G)\setminus (S\cup T)$ we obtain two components, which is contradictory to the $k$-vertex connectivity.
Is it possible to get some smaller $t(k,n)$ than $\frac{n-(k-1)}{2}$
such that if an $n$-vertex is $k$-vertex connected, then the graph is $t$-joined?
If not, adding any non-trivial condition to $k$-vertex connected will imply the smaller $t$?

The passage “is it possible to get some smaller $t(k,n)$
such that if an $n$-vertex connected graph is $t$-joined?” isn’t even a sentence. What is it that you want to know? An of course, then there’s also what do you know, what have you tried, etc.

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be vertex-disjoined copies of $K_{\ell}$ and let $G = K_k + (G_1 \cup G_2)$, where $F + H = \overline{\overline{F} \cup \overline{H}}$. It is easy to see that the graph $G$ is $k$-connected, because $G$ is union of two complete graphs $K_{k + \ell}$ sharing $k$ common vertices. At the same time the graph $G$ is not $\ell$-joined, since there are two disjoint vertex sets $V(G_1)$ and $V(G_2)$, each of cardinality $\ell$, such that there is no edge between them. Note that $n = |G| = 2\ell + k$ and $\ell = \frac{n - k}2$. So we can't reduce bound $t \ge \frac{n - k + 1}2$ without loosing property that $k$-connected graph on $n$ vertices is $t$-joined.
Among standard properties like bipartiteness, planarity, Hamiltonicity, factor-criticality or presence of perfect matching, regularity I don't see any that could help.
